# Python Module Not Found Error only for Compiled Script with Pyogrio Import

Tags: python-3.x, gis, geopandas

I'm on a Windows 10 work computer with Python 3 installed but not Python 2. Keeping the script simple here. This:

```
import pyogrio
print(pyogrio.__version__)
```

runs perfectly fine as a file.py script. When I compile (with pyinstaller) and run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Simple.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "pyogrio\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "pyogrio\core.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "pyogrio\\_io.pyx", line 1, in init pyogrio._io
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyogrio._geometry'
```

Looking in pyogrio's site packages folder there is no `\_geometry` but there are `\_geometry.pyx` and `\_geometry.pyd`.
I had a similar issue with `\_io` but I can see in their `\_envy.py` when the import fails it looks for gdal*.dll. Originally it couldn't find this either but I was able to force it and make it work.
No where in any of the visible code does it import or use `\_geometry` which is why I'm at a loss now.
What is it using to replace `\_geometry`? What do I need to add to my compiler to add in what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making it too complicated. While using Visual Studio Code pylance (the internal guy that checks modules?) was saying there was no pyogrio._geometry. But once it was compiled the import worked fine. Adding it to pyinstaller's --hidden-imports worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).